# How do I create global server config objects in sveltekit?

Tags: global-variables, config, sveltekit

In my sveltekit app, I keep doing this in my `+server.js` files throughout my routes:

```
import config from '$lib/server/config.js';
```

where the exported config object contains database connection details, etc. (some of which in turn come from environment variables), and this information is adapted to the environment I am running in (dev, prod, etc.).

I have two questions about this. First, is there a canonical place to put such a `config.js` file other than where I am putting it?

Second, is there a way to load this config object globally so I don't need to load it repeatedly in every `+server.js` file that needs this information? I could put it all in environment variables (via `.env`, for example), but then I lose some of the conveniences of my `config.js`.

Comment: Having the sensitive config in `lib/server` is a good idea, as SvelteKit will error if you try to use it in a file that ends up in the browser. What are you doing with the config in your files? Maybe you could create a [server hook](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks#server-hooks) instead if it fits your use case nicely.

Comment: Thanks @Tholle. At the moment, the config just contains database credentials and connection details so that data can be served via my API endpoints. The sensitive credentials are loaded from environment variables within my config.js. Maybe environment variables are the way to go, skipping config.js altogether as adovcated in [The Twelve Factor App](https://12factor.net/config)?

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you that all sensitive data should come from the environment so that you don't version control them, etc. If you just export environment variables from the config file in a more ergonomic manner you are still following The Twelve Factor App guidelines, since you are not hard coding anything into the config, so both approaches work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, it seems that `$lib/server` is a good home for configuration files. As far as global configuration variables, it appears that environment variables are the way to go, and can be set via [dotconfig](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-dotconfig)--making sure not to check your sensitive information into your repo where applicable (although I have gotten into the habit of creating a template called `.env.ex` to remind myself or others what variables it should contain).